# Why I can't define compare without constant

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

If I define my `compare` function like this:

```
bool compare(Student& a, Student& b)
{
    return a.n < b.n;
}
```

g++ will complain:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/algorithm:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >, _Tp = Student, _Compare = bool (*)(Student&, Student&)]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h:2261:78:   instantiated from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >, _Compare = bool (*)(Student&, Student&)]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h:2302:62:   instantiated from ‘void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >, _Size = long int, _Compare = bool (*)(Student&, Student&)]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h:5250:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >, _Compare = bool (*)(Student&, Student&)]’
main.cpp:38:51:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h:2229:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Student&’ from expression of type ‘const Student’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h:2232:4: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘Student&’ from expression of type ‘const Student’

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon May 28 08:05:35
```

But if I define the compare with `const` type, it will compile and works fine.

And here is all the code:

```
class Student {
public:
    Student(string);
    string n;

};

bool compare(Student& a, Student& b)
{
    return a.n < b.n;
}

Student::Student(string name) { n = name; }

int main()
{
    Student A = Student("A");
    Student B = Student("B");

    vector<Student> students;
    students.push_back(B);
    students.push_back(A);

    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);

    cout << "After sort" << endl;
    for(vector<Student>::iterator i = students.begin(); i != students.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "Student: " << i->n << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work without const?

Comment: That is an exercise from "Accererlated C++" basically ask me to remove a `const` from another function's parameter and see what else need to be modified. And by simply look up STD API, doesn't looks like `compare` itself require `const parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this implementation, `std::sort` uses

```
 const _Tp& std::__median(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare);
```

In your case, `_Tp` is student, and `_Compare` is `compare`.

So you basically have

```
const Student& std::__median(const Student&, const Student&, const Student&, 
                                                   bool (*)(Student&, Student&) )
```

or similar. Obviously, the callback can't be applied to the parameters are they are converted to `const`, so the failure.

Make the parameters to your `compare` method `const`.

Comment: Hi Luchina, how could I found the the information for std::sort, looking at source code? which one?

Comment: @pstar you can look in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_algo.h`. But I got all that from the error message.

Comment: But I can't find the `median` function with `const` in parameter signature in `stl_algo.h` neither in error message.

Comment: @pstar actually I was analyzing the code here - http://ideone.com/QyTNS. But it's similar.

Comment: @pstar: In your case, the culprit is actually [__unguarded_partition](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01494_source.html#l02283)

Comment: Yes, thank you Benjamin Lindley, I figure it out as well, must be different GCC version the error message is different. Interesting that the signature is `template<typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Tp>
    _RandomAccessIterator
    __unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
     _RandomAccessIterator __last, const _Tp& __pivot)' only the third parameter required to be `const`

Comment: @pstar: Those other two are iterators, they are taken by value, and modified within the function if you can read it.  It wouldn't make sense for them to be const.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley, you were right. I think I understand what's really happened finally. Thank you and Luchian Grigore for great explanations. I mark this as answer as I am more curious about details whereabouts my compiler require constant parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a requirement in the standard that says the parameters to the function must be const, so I believe your implementation is in error for rejecting it.  However, there is a requirement that the function not modify the arguments:

From the standard -- 25.4/2

> Compare is a function object type (20.8). The return value of the
>   function call operation applied to an object of type Compare, when
>   contextually converted to bool (4), yields true if the first argument
>   of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise. Compare comp
>   is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation. It is
>   assumed that comp will not apply any non-constant function through the
>   dereferenced iterator.

And the signature of `std::sort` from 25.4.1.1

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)
```

So since your function is not allowed to modify its arguments, it really should be taking them in as const, but the standard does not require that.  So while your implementation may be in error, I believe it is a forgivable error, as it manages to call attention to the fact that either your function is in violation of the standard by modifying its arguments, or it is not const-correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it const since it leaves the two parameters the same.

Comment: Yes - and sorry never noticed that.